# Case when statement to categorized values

Tags: sql, oracle, case

TABLE_1:

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 100 |
| A | Apple | 100 |
| A | Apple | 56 |
| A | Apple | 44 |
| B | Banana | 100 |
| C | Cucumber | 93 |
| C | Cucumber | 7 |

I want to use a case when statement to categorize Col 1 as "good" or "bad" into a new column. I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Col_1
   , CASE WHEN Col_3 = 100 THEN 'good'
      ELSE 'bad'
   END AS STATUS
FROM TABLE_1
```

This results in the TABLE_2:

| Col_1 | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| A | good |
| A | bad |
| B | good |
| C | bad |

How do I fix this so that if A is both good and bad, it will just take the bad status? I would like TABLE_3 to be my result

TABLE_3:

| Col_1 | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| A | bad |
| B | good |
| C | bad |

Comment: You can do a GROUP BY.

Comment: BTW. that's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for recommendation. I ended up using AVG() then Group by and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with table_1 (col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 'A', 'Apple',  100 from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 'Apple',  100 from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 'Apple',   56 from dual union all
  5     select 'A', 'Apple',   44 from dual union all
  6     select 'B', 'Banana' ,100 from dual union all
  7     select 'C', 'Cucumber',93 from dual union all
  8     select 'C', 'Cucumber', 7 from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select col1,
 11    case when max(col3) = 100 and min(col3) < 100 then 'bad'
 12         when max(col3) = 100                     then 'good'
 13         else 'bad'
 14    end status
 15  from table_1
 16  group by col1;

COL1  STATUS
----- ----------
A     bad
B     good
C     bad

SQL>
```

---

Or even simpler

```
 10  select col1,
 11    min(case when col3 = 100 then 'good'
 12             else 'bad'
 13        end
 14       ) status
 15  from table_1
 16  group by col1;

COL1  STATUS
----- ----------
A     bad
B     good
C     bad

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that just by using min()

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col_1
      ,CASE WHEN min(Col_3) = 100 THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END AS STATUS
  FROM TABLE_1
 group by col_1
 order by col_1;
```

It'll take the minimal value of col_3 and will return "bad" when there a records with < 100

Answer (score 0):

You can GROUP BY and use a aggregation function

```
SELECT 
   Col_1
   , MIN(CASE WHEN Col_3 = 100 THEN 'good'
      ELSE 'bad'
   END) AS STATUS
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY Col_1
```

| COL_1 | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| A | bad |
| B | good |
| C | bad |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TSWvoMI0)